# Getting dictionary from a manager as global variable

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying the following code before main

```
manager = Manager()
general_d = manager.dict()
```

Then in main 
I define the following

```
  p = Pool(4)  # however many process you want to spawn
  p.map(proc_file, directoary_names)

def proc_file(directoary_names):
    try:
        process_data(directoary_names)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      pass
```

The problem is I get frozen exception is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')

The main problem is I'm processing many files and I'm getting results from each file, so the problem how would I get the results for example from sensors ( s1 to s8) with time stamps for each sensor and merge them in **order** of time stamps...

A pseudo code would be helpfull.

In process data, I process the file, read it's data, then I put the results into global **lists**

```
             S1.append(df_conv['C_strain_COY'].median())
             S2.append(df_conv['C_strain_CUY'].median())
             S3.append(df_conv['C_strain_ROX'].median())
             S4.append(df_conv['C_strain_CUX'].median())
             S5.append(df_conv['C_strain_CMX'].median())
             S6.append(df_conv['C_strain_COX'].median())
             S7.append(df_conv['C_strain_LOX'].median())

             T1.append(df_conv['C_temp_CUY'].median())
             T2.append(df_conv['C_temp_COY'].median())
             T3.append(df_conv['C_temp_CUX'].median())
             T4.append(df_conv['C_temp_CMX'].median())
             T5.append(df_conv['C_temp_COX'].median())
```

Comment: Could you clarify "The problem is I get frozen exception is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')" ? What does process_data do, does it return e.g. a dict?

Comment: @randomwalker I already modified the post to clarify what does process data do

Comment: Given the lists S1, ..., S7, which contain DataFrames, you could use pd.concat to get a DataFrame for each sensor (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html). This DataFrame can then be sorted along the timestamp column. If you also want to merge all sensor data to a single dataframe there is pd.merge, pd.merge_asof.

Comment: @randomwalker thanks for your suggestions, but should I need the a dictionary from a manager to do that ? or the current lists with merging and the stuff is only what is needed ?

Comment: would you show a pseudo code as an answer for your idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Say S1 to S7 are lists of Pandas DataFrames, each containing data of a specific sensor and an according timestamp for each data entry.

`import pandas as pd`

Create a joint DataFrame for each sensor

`df_S1 = pd.concat(S1)`

Sort these DataFrame along the timestamp axis

`df_S1 = df_S1.sort_values(by='timestamps')`

Now, if you want to merge all sensors together in a single DataFrame, checkout [Pandas' tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) to decide which function you need (e.g. pd.merge or pd.merge_asof). If you go with pd.merge, you can loop over df_S1, ..., df_S7, since pd.merge supports only merging two DataFrames.

Comment: The problem is timestamps are generated before processing the data.. as the function process_data doesn't accept more than one iterable, how to solve that issue

Comment: Is there a timestamp for each file or does every entry in the file has its own timestamp?

Comment: if you look at the code, you will there is a timestamp for each file.. Please take a look at the code... I don't know how to generate the Sx and Tx as dataframes

Comment: Can you tell me how to construct S1 to S7 ? as list od pandas dataframes ?